# Attempt to write a read-only database - System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, sqlite

I'm having a little bit of a problem that I thought was related to Security but, turns out can't be as I did almost everything ...

Plenty of information on this on the web but nothing has an answer to fix the issue.

Let me tell my steps:

- Have a Website on VS2k8 that when I debug or start from Cassini, all works fine
- When setting up IIS 7.5 (Win7) to point to this website and after adding IIS_IUSRS Modify rights I get the error
- Same thing using IIS 6.0!

**Img: Security on Database File from IIS 7.5**

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-25_1028.png))</sub>

*Note that all other files and folders have the same rights as above*

The full Error is:

```
Log: Executing query on SQLite Database

Message ***************************************
Attempt to write a read-only database
attempt to write a readonly database

Stack Trace ***********************************
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at soDatabaseManager.CommitPersonsToKitchenDatabase() in c:\Adwiza\Kitchen\App_Code\soDatabaseManager.cs:line 242
```

---

**P.S.** **Keep in mind** that this has to work with IIS 6 (windows 2003) as well, the IIS 7.5 is only for troubleshooting as we have more control in everything...

Comment: Did you check read only state of file?

Comment: Yes I did, it is not read-only, non of the files in IIS are :-/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that the anonymous web user account (NETWORK SERVICE or [maybe something else](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/03/13/changes-to-application-pool-identities-in-iis-7-5-beta.aspx)) under which your web application executes has read/write/create/delete access to the folder where the sqlite database resides.

Comment: under IIS 7.5 you can choose wither to use a USER or Application, my anonymous User is IUSR (as you can see, it exists in the Security Panel) and I have the same error on using Application Pool identity (img: http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-02-25_1150.png )

Answer (score 3):

The other answer give me an idea about the problem, but my solution was a bit differente. 
The problem was that the user did not have permissions to modify the folder and the .db file.
So I give permission to the user **Everyone** (collective group for **Authenticated Users** and **Guest**). The permisions on **NETWORK SERVICE** (or similars) did not solve in my case.

**Note:** The `IIS` must be restarted, after the change, to load the change made.

Comment: For me, it was the application pool identity, but +1 for advice to restart - but that only applied to the application pool itself, in my case. Not all of IIS.

Answer (score -1):

ss----[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEdQ.jpg)

You should also do this. error for--->Unable to open the database file
You must add a connection string.--"Version=3;Mode=ReadWrite;New=False;Compress=True;Journal Mode=Off;";

Comment: Images of text is a bad idea (they can't be searched, external sites take them down sometimes), rather copy and paste the text.