# Unable to write to database

Tags: c#, winforms, security, sqlite, readonly

Hi there
I developed an applicaiton that uses SQLlite database but after making setup project and installing it i get exceptions when writing to it

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Attempt to write a read-only database
```

what is the problem?

it works fine while developing at visual studio

**EDIT**
I added user Everyone and assigned it all rights to the folder where the database is placed.that folder was created by the installer and it worked now but what should I do to avoid this ..........because where this application will be deployed they are not much computer literate to do this manually

Comment: Where on the disk is the database located, exactly?

Comment: Have you checked the permission of the account used to ran the application?

Comment: in bin folder and when deployed then it is where exe is placed.i read data but cannot write

Comment: I added user Everyone and assigned it all rights to the folder where the database is placed.that folder was created by the installer and it worked now but what should I do to avoid this ..........because where this application will be deployed they are not much computer literate to do this manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link forum, the common root cause is permission issue.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/864/7498.aspx

**Update**

Why not encrypt the sqlite database

[Encrypt SQLite database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c/1261765#1261765)

Comment: I added user Everyone and assigned it all rights to the folder where the database is placed.that folder was created by the installer and it worked now but what should I do to avoid this ..........because where this application will be deployed they are not much computer literate to do this manually

Comment: Do you really expect the "computer illeterate" to tinker the sqlite database file? They would rather use the winform :-). Anyway, try to grant least privileges.

Comment: actually this application is used for data entry only and staff will do it.Anyway it would be great if you give me a link how to implement it?does it involve `System.Management.Instrumentation`

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I've updated the post and suggest that you encrypt the database.

Answer (score 2):

[Attempt to write a read-only database - System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333047/attempt-to-write-a-read-only-database-system-data-sqlite)

Comment: I added user Everyone and assigned it all rights and it worked now but what should I do to avoid this ..........because where this application will be deployed they are not much computer literate to do this manually

Comment: @Afnan try to reduce the right, granting [least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Comment: well if i grant least then same error will occur because it wont have permissions....rite?

Answer (score 1):

The database should not be in the same folder as the exe file. The location of exe files, i.e. program files, is protected for security reasons, and modifying the permissions is not the way to go.

You should put data that needs to be written to in the users data area, or the data area for all users.

You can locate this folder using SHGetSpecialFolderPath