# SQLite attempt to write a readonly database error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a console application that populates a SQLite database. When the application runs by itself, I don't get any errors. If I run multiple instances of the application, where each application is in its own folder and each populates its own database I'll occasionally get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): Attempt to write a read-only database
attempt to write a readonly database
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I know the DB isn't read-only because it has already written data to that database. Also, the app continues on and will continue populating data to that database. I haven't reproduced the error when only a single instance of the application is running.

I've tried using the pragma to have both the journal and temp_store in memory instead of to a file in case there could be some contention across applications there, but I still get the error. I do always get the error in the same method, which is the first time an insert would happen for the connection. To give a general idea of what the application does, it loops over cases, gathers info about those cases (not from SQLite), then writes results to the SQLite database.

I don't know what else to try.

*edit
I am also using the PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY. When inserting data into the SQLite database, I first run a BEGIN statement, then a bunch of inserts before the END statement. The error occurs on the first insert.

Comment: _"I've tried using the pragma to have both the journal and temp_store in memory instead of to a file in case there could be some contention across applications there"_ There won't be. How are you opening the database? Is the folder the database is in writeable?

Comment: Yes, the folder the database is in is writeable. Most iterations are properly inserting data into the database. I'm opening the database just through a using statement around the SQLiteConnection.

Answer (score 11):

It is a permissions issue.

Make sure that your web application that is hosted has add/write/create/delete access to the folder where the sqlite database resides.

For more details, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333047/attempt-to-write-a-read-only-database-system-data-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks, but how can it be a permissions issue if it is random? The application successfully writes to the database. It is only on random iterations that it gets this error.

Comment: I agree with @UWSkeletor. What else?

Comment: This has worked for my scenario.. The service was running under `www-data` user, the DB file was created under my custom user. The solution of adding the custom user to `www-data` group seems to have resolved the problem (at least for now) `usermod -aG www-data custom_user`. Also I am not sure if it's related, but I am using the journal mode `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`  for the sqlite db which presumably helps with concurrency issues, which might, or might not be related to the issues the author was having. So I recommend using this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be that The database  file is not supported by the MigrationAssembly.

The same exception is thrown when the EF tries to migrate on a file expected to be a SQLite database which is fi. a text file.